# Object Turns Pitch Black When Roughness is Set to 0 in Eevee

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, roughness

I'm trying to create a transparent water texture in eevee but when I set the roughness to zero using the principled shader the object becomes pitch black.

Here it is set to a roughness of 0.03.
[image: roughness 0.03]

And here when it is set to 0.
[image: roughness 0]

Is there some way to fix this or do I just set it to a value between 0 and 1?

edit: here is the node setup.

[image: Node setup]

late edit: I know this is late but the preview sphere in the shading workspace is also pitch black and this appears in all my files, both new and old. The preview sphere used to be reflective with the hdr background but now not even putting in a new hdr background doesn't change it.

[image: Material Preview Sphere]

Comment: That isn’t supposed to happen. Can you add screenshots of your node setup?

Comment: I've added the node setup to the post.

Comment: Hmm… highly unusual and exotic node setup there… nope. ☺️ Are all other settings in the scene default?

Comment: can you add your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added a late update to the post. I think the sphere may have something to do with the issue.

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? In Blender 2.92 everything is fine. But in Blender 2.93 there is seems to be a bug. If I set the *Roughness* value to a value lower than 0.004 the object gets instantly pitch black. The HDRI preview sphere is also pitch black like yours. Eevee and the material preview mode are affected. Cycles is fine. Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228640/hdri-sphere-appears-black

Comment: Blender 2.93. Looks like I'm not the only one with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set 0.5 for alpha
2. Transmission to 0
3. Under material > Setting > Blend set to alpha hased or blend.